# How to replace long one html-like string in files across multiple files in directories[sed,grep]?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I need to replace:

```
 <m2: SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png"/></m2:VisualElements>
```

with this long string:

```
<m2:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" />
    <m2:InitialRotationPreference>
      <m2:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
    </m2:InitialRotationPreference>
```

in many similar Package.appxmanifest file - not txt files. These file can be opened through texteditor

sed command did work, but only in one file.

```
sed -i '' 's/SplashScreen/xxxx/g' Package.appxmanifest
```

I want this replace done in all package.appxmanifest files across directories recursively.

Answer (score 2):

attach to `find`

```
find yourpath -name Package.appxmanifest -exec sed -i ... {} \;
```

fill in the `...` with your sed script.